# What chapter of the light novel does the anime Mondaiji-tachi end on?

Tags: mondaiji

To my sadness, I enjoyed the anime and the OVA very much but I cannot seem to find where the anime left off in terms of the light novel.

Could someone tell me what it left off on?

Answer (score 1):

The animation covers vol. 1 and 2 so you can safely start from Vol. 3 onwards. Though it would be in your best interests to start from the beginning since as any adaptation, there's a lot more world-building in the novels and it can help explain some of the stuff that was a bit dodgy in the anime adaptation. But all in all, it was quite a decent adaptation with very little pacing issues in my opinion so you can safely start from Vol. 3, I started reading from there back then but it was more of a compromise since they didn't translate the first 2 volumes until later on.